# How to return an exit code from the main block in Nim?

Tags: return, program-entry-point, exit-code, nim-lang

In Nim, to write code that executes as a sort of main function, you do (similar to the is main checks in Python):

```
when isMainModule:
    echo ("Hello, Nim!")
```

However, for the life of me, I can't figure out how to return an error code. Traditionally there has always been an option to make main functions return `int`, but since this is not actually in a `proc`, it doesn't seem like you can `return`; the only thing I've figured out how to do is to `raise` an exception. Surely there is a way to just control whether your exit code is zero or not?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think `system.quit` may be what you're looking for. According to the [Nim docs](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#quit,int):

> `proc quit(errorcode: int = QuitSuccess) {..}`
>
> Stops the program immediately with an exit code.
>
> The proc `quit(QuitSuccess)` is called implicitly when your nim program finishes without incident for platforms where this is the expected behavior. A raised unhandled exception is equivalent to calling `quit(QuitFailure)`.

Comment: Thanks, total fail of Googlefu I guess! The fact that this is called implicitly at the end anyway is what confirms this answer as correct.